# Why does "large hill" make sense as the translation for 대구(大邱)?

Tags: etymology, place-names

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daegu states that the name of the City means, literally 'large hill' - from 大 (large) and 邱 (hill).

However, the same page [also states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daegu#Topography):

> Daegu sits in a basin surrounded by low mountains. Palgongsan to the north, Biseulsan to the south, Waryongsan to the west, and a series of smaller hills in the east. The Geumho River flows along the northern and eastern edges of the city, emptying in the Nakdong River west of the city.

That is also my memory of Daegu - that it is in a valley, rather than being on any particular hill.

Should '大邱' be taken to mean 'large hill', and if so, which large hill is referred to?

Comment: Well, the answer certainly isn't in the primary historical sources. Samguk Sagi just mentions that King Gyeongdeok of Silla changed the name from 達句火 to 大丘 (三國史記・卷第三十四：大丘縣，本達句火縣，景德王改名).

Comment: Also, see https://www.kci.go.kr/kciportal/ci/sereArticleSearch/ciSereArtiView.kci?sereArticleSearchBean.artiId=ART000882787 - I also tend to think that the Hanja name 大丘 is a transcription.

Answer (score 3):

From [Naver지식in](https://kin.naver.com/qna/detail.nhn?d1id=12&dirId=1203&docId=288768485&qb=64yA6rWsIOydtOumhCDsnKDrnpg=&enc=utf8&section=kin&rank=1&search_sort=0&spq=0),

> 대구의 옛이름은 다벌, 달벌, 달불성, 달구벌, 달구화. 대구등으로 바뀌었다.
>
> "불"과 "벌"은 우리말의 모음접변에 의한 것으로서 같은 말인데 평지, 평야, 촌락, 성읍을 뜻하는 말이라 한다.
>
> "達(달)"의 뜻은 圓(원), 周(주)등 넓은 공간을 뜻하므로, 결국 達句火(달구화)와 大邱(대구)는 서로 같은 뜻이 된다.

So if this uncited answer is to be believed, 대구 actually corresponds to 達句火(달구화) which means "wide area", which I suppose is closer to the actual description of 대구 as a valley.

It further goes on to say

> 達句伐(달구벌)이 大丘(대구)로 바뀐 것은 통일 이후 唐(당) 문화의 영향을 크게 받은 신라가 모든 제도 문물을 중국식으로
>   정비해 가는 변화의 한 산물이다. 종래 여러 가지로 불리우던 벼슬 이름이나 지방 이름을 원칙적으로 2자의 한자로 개칭하였다.
>   개칭의 방법은 음을 딴 것, 뜻을 따르는 것, 아름답게 고치는 것, 글자를 줄이는 것 등이 있는데 달구벌이 大丘(대구)로 바뀐
>   것은 음을 딴 경우에 해당한다 하겠다.

So it looks more like the 구 got the particular 한자 as an effort to change place names to Hanja characters and reduce their length, as part of the then government's policy

It says further

> 『丘』자가 『邱』로 바뀐 것은 조선왕조 英正(영정)시대부터이다. 1750年(英祖 26) 『丘』자를 다른 자로 고치자는 상소가
>   있었다. 『丘』자가 孔子(공자)의 이름자인 까닭에서였다. 영조는 이것을 신기를 좋아하는 경망한 풍조의 소산이라 하여 신랄하게
>   비판하였다. 그러나 대구 사람들은 점차 達(달)자 대신 脚(각)자를 쓰기 시작하였다.

which brings the name to the currently used characters

So it doesn't seem it is referring to any mountain in particular, but I hope someone can find a better sourced answer